# How to run cli created cordova project, in visual studio?

Tags: android, angular, visual-studio, cordova

I have created a cordova project using command line and running everything using VS code. But, the problem is now I want to push my app to playstore and that I cannot do with VS Code. So for that I want to run my project in Visual Studio 2017. Is there anyway to run the CLI generated cordova app in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple links related to running a Cordova App in VS. Seems like you'll have to plug in an android device, run an android emulator, or run it in a browser:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/run-your-app/run-app-android?view=toolsforcordova-2017#google-android-emulator